# Spring Security OAuth2 timestamp/logging to the database

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on a Spring Boot application.I would like to take a timestamp of actions such as login time,password validation successful/unsuccessful, number of successful or failed attempts along with the user's ID and store it the database.In general I would like to keep track of user's actions and store it in the database.
I'm using spring security oauth2 and storing the users credentials in a database.
How do I do this?Any example or links will be of immense help.

Thanks in advance